# Correct order to upload images on firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

To upload images for an object created by a user I store the images (selected by the user) in an array 'imagesList' as a File. When the user clicked upload (whole object) the following method saves the data on firebase:

```
TextButton(
     onPressed: () async {
        await uploadImage();
        await jobService.createJob(Job(
            titleTextEditorController.text.trim(),
            category,
            false,
            false,
            finalImageList));
        },
       child: Text('upload')),
```

The List finalImageList is filled in the first method 'uploadImage()'. I sourced it out in another method to get the await statement. The Code:

```
uploadImage() async {
  for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
    _imageFile = imageList[i];

    String fileName = Path.basename(_imageFile!.path);

    Reference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');

    firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': fileName});

    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_imageFile!);
    uploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      try {
        imageUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
        print('imageUrl' + imageUrl);
        finalImageList.add(imageUrl);
      } catch (onError) {
        print("Upload Error");
      }
    });
    await Future.value(uploadTask)
        .then((value) => {print('Upload file path ${value.ref.fullPath}')})
        .onError((error, stackTrace) =>
            {print('Upload file path error ${error.toString()}')});
  }
}
```

But the method is not fast enough to store the imageUrl's in `finalImageList`, so the Images is online but its not connected to the object in firebase. Is there a possibility to upload it immediately or the save the imageUrl correctly? Or is my code just in the wrong order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FlutterFire `UploadTask` class extends `Future`, which means that you can use `await` on it to wait until the upload is done.

That means you can write your code much simpler as:

```
await reference.putFile(_imageFile!);
imageUrl = await reference.getDownloadURL();
finalImageList.add(imageUrl);
print('Upload file path ${value.ref.fullPath}')
```

With this change, your `uploadImage` will only complete *after* the download URL was added to `finalImageList`.